# Inline assembly __sync_fetch_and_add and __sync_add_and_fetch

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, built-in

The GCC builtin `__sync_fetch_and_add` is an implementation of the x86 inline assembly:

```
 asm("lock; xaddl %%eax, %2;"
      :"=a" (val)
      : "a" (val), "m" (*ptr) : )
```

How can I implement this inline assembly using the `addl` instruction instead of `xaddl`?

And another question that I have is how would be the x86 inline assembly of the builtin `__sync_add_and_fetch` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Builtins do not necessarily correspond with a single well defined chunk of assembly code. In particular both `__sync_add_and_fetch` and `__sync_fetch_and_add` will generate `lock addl` instead of `lock xaddl` if the result is not live out of the builtin, and they may generate `lock incl` if the result is not live out and the second argument is known to have the value 1.

It is not clear what you mean by "how can I implement this inline assembly". Assembly is something that you write or generate, not something that you implement (unless you are writing an assembler).

Comment: The "how can I implement" I mean how  can I write this instruction in inline assembly

Comment: See the gcc docs on inline assembly at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.